# SSIS consequences TABLOCK

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a package that reads data from tableA and inserts data into tableB. This package can run in parallel multiple times (usually 3 to 5) but never reading the same data. Lets say it has a flag customerID on both tables so each execution of the package will be reading data from a particular customerID.

I realized that if I don't use TABLELOCK on my destination the load occurs a lot faster. I believe that's because each execution of the package is inserting data on tableB at the same time and even though some locking at the page level is occurring, the whole table is not locked.

So my question is, Is that any issues on not using TABLELOCK on the destination?

PS: I'm using fast load and the customerId is the clustered index on table B.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your parallel runs are invoking unique customer IDs, then no, there's no real issue performance wise or deadlocking-wise.

There are really only two issues you should be at least aware of:

1) Order in which your parallel tasks insert data, and subsequent reads of tableB. Depending on how real-time your reads from tableB are, TABLOCK will help ensure (but still not guarantee - if one customer has 10,000 rows and another only has 1, that second customer might "leapfrog" the first in the Data Flow task processing) that your parallel runs are still processed in the order in which they were executed. So you might end up in scenarios where data is not available exactly when you think it is, so if order is important (which I guess it isn't or you shouldn't run in parallel) at least be aware of this.

2) Potentially even if you don't enable TABLOCK if an insert is big enough it can automatically jump from ROWLOCK to TABLOCK, so you might still end up with delays and staggered finishes to some of your jobs.